# compare successive elements in Vector by using Iterator

Tags: c++, vector

**Problem:** Check successive elements in vectors `if v[i] < v[i+1] + 1`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int>v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    for(auto &i: v)
    {
        cout << (i+1) << endl;
    }
    //SIMILAR TO THIS FOR LOOP
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size() - 1;i++)
    {
        if(v[i] < v[i+1] + 1){cout << "ok" << endl;}
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Questions:**

- by using `for(auto &i: v)`how can I use the index in order to compare two successive elements?
- I don't want to use the second for loop in the source code because vector **size** might change. By using auto i don't have to worry if elements are erased and the vector is resized is that right?

Comment: You more or less can't today. Perhaps in the future we will get something like python's `zip`.

Comment: You can't. `i` is not an iterator. Use a regular `for` loop with an iterator or an index.

Comment: There are somethings you just can't do with a ranged based for loop. In this case use iterators

Comment: @IgorTandetnik `i` is considered what in the range loop

Comment: `i` would be `int&` - a reference to each successive element.

Comment: Your `for` loop has undefined behaviour, you access `v[i+1]` when `i` is the last index

Comment: //////////////////// del

Comment: @Fl0 so i will just have to correct the index in question (2). what i mean is that if i remove an element then i'll have to decrease the index (i) by 1

Comment: use erase/remove algorythm if you want to delete items. please show us what you want to do with loop, there is many ways to do something in c++...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; j < v.size();i++)
{
    if(v[i] < v[i+1] + 1){cout << "ok" << endl;}
}
```

This loop has undefined behaviour, you access `v[i+1]` when `i` is the last index. You would need the condition to be `i+1 < v.size()`

> - by using for(auto &i: v)how can I use the index in order to compare two successive elements?

Because `std::vector` is guaranteed to have contiguous storage it is possible to access the next element when using a range-based `for` loop:

```
for (auto& i : v)
  if (i < *(&i+1) + 1) {cout << "ok" << endl;}
```

However this has the same problem as your `for` loop, it will access past-the-end of the vector, and in this case there is no way to stop it because you can't use a range-based `for` loop if you want to stop iteration before the end of the range. You would need to do:

```
size_t count = 0;
for (auto& i : v)
  if (++count < v.size() && i < *(&i+1) + 1) {cout << "ok" << endl;}
```

And at this point you might as well just use a normal `for` loop, it's simpler and clearer.

> - I don't want to use the second for loop in the source code because vector size might change. By using auto i don't have to worry if elements are erased and the vector is resized is that right?

No! You **must not** use range-based `for` loops for anything funky like iterating over a vector that are being modified, it just goes from the first element to the last element of a fixed range, nothing fancy.

If you try to use it while the vector is being modified then either it will go off the end of the vector, or if the vector grows and reallocates then the iterators used behind the scenes by the range-based loop will become invalidated.

If you need to do something more complicated than just visiting every element in turn then **do not use a range-based `for` loop**.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could keep it simple. If you have to declare a variable outside the loop anyway, you could then just write:

```
int index = 0;  
for (auto &i : v)
{
    if (index + 1 < v.size() && i < v[++index] + 1) { cout << "ok" << endl; }
}
```

I think `v[++index]` could be a little more faster than `*(&i+1) + 1`.

Comment: When `v.size() == 1` this has undefined behaviour. I would expect `*(&i+1)` to be faster, since the compiler knows it is the element adjacent to `i`. It's harder for it to know that `i` and `v[index]` are the same element.

Comment: @JonathanWakely not any more.

Comment: `index < v.size() && i < v[++index] + 1` should be `index + 1 < v.size() && i < v[++index] + 1` and the `v.size() > 1` is unnecessary

Comment: @BeyelerStudios, you're rigth!